# \renewcommand{\bibheadtitle} not working with hyperref package

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, hyperref, subdividing, multibib

I had a document that properly divided my biblography into three sections with the help of **multibib** package, and forcing the Biliography Section Titles by means of a **\renewcommand{\bibheadtitle}**, but when I add the **hyperref** package I loose the titles of my Bibliographies and they go back to the standard "References" name.

How can I preserve the names of my biblographies while using **hyperref**?

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\usepackage{authordate1-4}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{defi}{Definición}[subsection]
\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{teorema}[defi]{Teorema}
\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{coro}[defi]{Corolario}   

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pri,sec}{Primari Sources,Secondary Sources}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\small}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, backref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\include{aaa}
\include{bbb}

\renewcommand{\bibheadtitle}{Mixed Sources}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{Bibfile}

\renewcommand{\bibheadtitle}{Primary sources}
\bibliographystylepri{authordate1}
\bibliographypri{Bibfile}

\renewcommand{\bibheadtitle}{Secondary sources}
\bibliographystylesec{authordate1}
\bibliographysec{Bibfile}

\end{document}
```

I enclose a Minumun Working Example:

```
\documentclass[spanish,1p,20pt]{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{prix,secx}{Primary Sources,Secondary Sources}


\begin{document} 

Text

\cite{RefWorks:33}

\citeprix{RefWorks:22}

\citesecx{RefWorks:23}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{Borradores}

\bibliographystyleprix{alpha}
\bibliographyprix{Borradores}

\bibliographystylesecx{alpha}
\bibliographysecx{Borradores}

\end{document}
```

This sample works fine until I add the following *Authordate* package, that I need to format the style I'm forced to use:

```
\usepackage{authordate1-4}
```

Whether it is before or after  *\usepackage{multibib}* makes no difference. The problem is that my section **names** carefully inserted by *multibib* package. The sections itself are preserved so I tell myself: perhaps I can just rename the sections. And certainly I can by coding a *\renewcommand{\bibtitle}{Fuentes primarias}* to obtain a new Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass[spanish,1p,20pt]{article}

\usepackage{authordate1-4}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{prix,secx}{Primary Sources,Secondary Sources}


\begin{document}

Text

\cite{RefWorks:33}

\citeprix{RefWorks:22}

\citesecx{RefWorks:23}


\renewcommand{\bibheadtitle}{Mixed Sources}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{Borradores}

\renewcommand{\bibtitle}{Fuentes primarias}
\bibliographystyleprix{authordate1}
\bibliographyprix{Borradores}

\renewcommand{\bibtitle}{Fuentes secundarias}
\bibliographystylesecx{authordate1}
\bibliographysecx{Borradores}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can try to load `authordate1-4` after `hyperref`.

Comment: +1 Thank you Marco. I think I've found that somehow I changed a \bibtitle for a \bibheadtitle in addition to the use of hyperref. So \renewcommand{\bibtitle} was not there. Your advice of working on the MWE has been basic to get the error trapped.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a misspelled command name and was solved by the OP.